# Function to remove duplicates from entire sheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot get the function below to work. Ideally I would like to create a function that will automatically identify how many used columns are in the sheet then pass that as an array to the delete duplicates. I cannot understand why it is not working. I can confirm that these sheets have headers and multiple rows. I keep on getting error 5 when I try to remove duplicates using the array.

```
        ReDim colary(1 To wbDestination.Sheets(1).Range("XX1").End(xlToLeft).Column)
        For i = 1 To UBound(colary)
            colary(i) = i
        Next i

        wbDestination.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:" & wbDestination.Sheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Evaluate(colary), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Evaluate(colary)` just be `colary`

Comment: I found a solution here at the end answered by Osuchov: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834596/assign-array-to-removeduplicates-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were wanting to create a function, here is a method

```
Sub RemoveDupes(ByVal entireRng As Range, ByVal col As Integer, Optional ByVal containsHeaders As Boolean = True)
    Dim retVal As Integer
    If containsHeaders = True Then
        retVal = xlYes
    Else
        retVal = xlNo
    End If
    entireRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=col, Header:=retVal
End Sub
```

The routine isn't really less work than just typing it out, but you can use it however you desire.

If you want to check multiple columns, then for the `col` variable you can pass an array.

Answer (score 0):

This function remove duplicates from all columns in current worksheet

```
Sub RemDupCol() 'remove duplicates from all columns
Dim rng As Range
Dim cols As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = [A1].CurrentRegion 'range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns
ReDim cols(0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1) 'resize a dynamic array already declared
For i = 0 To UBound(cols) 'Loop for all columns
cols(i) = i + 1
Next i
rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(cols), Header:=xlYes 'Removes duplicate values from a range of values.
'Array of indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate information. first row contains header information.
End Sub
```